# Open nfc example application

Tags: android, nfc, open-nfc

I just downloaded the Open NFC API and it comes with an example project called `NFCBrowser`.
I have gone through the PDF they have provided for the configuration of the AVD. But in the page no. 10 it says:

> 3.4 Launching of the AVD and starting of the Open NFC stack
>
> The connection center is used by the “Open NFC for Android” add-on to access to NFC controller.Prior launching the AVD, the Connection center must be launched and configured to accept client connections from other machines, as shown below:"

and I am not able to find connection center as mentioned in the PDF.

I am also getting this error when try to run this application which says:

> no NFC access granted at all for the application

Comment: I suggest contacting OpenNFC directly and ask them      http://www.open-nfc.org/contacts.html

Answer (score 3):

To use the NFC API, applications must request permission from the user by declaring

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC">
```

in their manifest files.

Answer (score 0):

The connection center is a Windows app that comes bundled with the Core Edition of Open NFC. You will need it to config the NFCC emulator. 
The NFCC emulator, and the corresponding kernel image that is needed to run the emulator, is provided with the OpenNFC SDK Addon (if you don't know where to get it, let me know). See my [post on a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770774/getting-started-with-open-nfc-emulator/6782352#6782352) for some more details.
There is no corresponding Linux version of the connection center AFAIK, as I've just found out--I am on a Ubuntu host.