# how to install the open NFC add-on in Android SDK

Tags: android, add-on, open-nfc

I have follow the steps in [Open NFC Simulator Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234263/open-nfc-simulator-usage?lq=1,when) I downloaded the open NFC, I don't exactly know how to install the open NFC add-on in Android SDK as mentioned in step 2. The version of open NFC I downloaded is Delivery_2012-12-14_android-4.2.1_r1_OpenNFC_4.5.1. And the Android SDK version is 4.2.1.I will appreciate for your help, thanks!