# Open NFC Simulator not working for Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, nfc, android-virtual-device, open-nfc

I'm trying to emulate NFC card reading in Android Emulator, using Open NFC v4.5.2 for that purpose.

I have followed all steps indicated here:

[HOWTO use the NFC Simulator with the Open NFC add-on included in the delivery](http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/android/#addon_simulator)

I have also tried with insturctions from other StackOverflow posts such [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770774/getting-started-with-open-nfc-emulator) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234263/open-nfc-simulator-usage?lq=1,when), with no success.

When I start the emulator I'm not able to turn-on NFC in `Settings->Wireless & networks->NFC`, and NFC Controller Simulator doesn't show any activity:

[image: Emulator NFC settings]
[image: NFC simulator]

Following is the capture of the *Connection Center*:

[image: Connection Center]

Any hints on how can I make this to work?

**EDIT:** 
Following is the output I get from `adb logcat`:

```
W/Settings(  381): Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Sett
ings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
W/Trace   (  447): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
W/Trace   (  447): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
I/NfcService(  381): Enabling NFC
I/packages/apps/Nfc/nxp/jni/com_android_nfc_NativeNfcManager.cpp(  381): com_and
roid_nfc_NfcManager_initialize
E/packages/apps/Nfc/nxp/jni/com_android_nfc_NativeNfcManager.cpp(  381): can't i
nitialize NFC Manager
W/NfcService(  381): Error enabling NFC
```

I'm working on a Windows 8 Pro machine.

Comment: I have the same problem. I hope somebody solves this soon...

Comment: Do you have any updates for you question? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have suspicion that it might depend on versions of image of Android inside the emulator, have you used the image (or whole set) from:

http://open-nfc.org/wp/home/downloads/

or from Google distribution?