# Configuring OpenNFC Emulation on Windows 7

Tags: android, android-emulator, open-nfc

**Usual context:** I’m new to Android development and do not have access to any real hardware.

**Objective:** For now, I’m just trying to install and configure OpenNFC as supplied. My ultimate objective is to be able to run two simulators which will communicate via simulated NFC; one on which I can run Android apps and the other a PIN Pad simulation. I’m doing this as a training exercise to prepare for an anticipated project using this technology in a few months.
Problem: I can’t get the Open NFC AVD to start up successfully. The last two steps of the instructions for how to use the NFC Simulator with the Open NFC add-on (http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/android/) are:

> 9. Now, start your AVD again. You should get additional activity in the Connection
>    Center window, showing that client source "nfcc_hal" has connected.
> 10. Once the AVD image has booted, you can see the reader modes started on the
>     NfcSimulator software. You can start emulating NFC events from this point

I think step 9 has worked (but I’m not certain!) but not step 10.

I have installed:

- Android Studio 1.1.0 (and various packages managed by the SDK Manager)
- OpenNFC Core (Open NFC - Core Edition v4.5.2 (16234).zip)
- OpenNFC SDK (Delivery_2012-12-14_android-4.2.1_r1_OpenNFC_4.5.1.tar.gz)
- EchoTool – as suggested here ([Getting started with Open NFC emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770774/getting-started-with-open-nfc-emulator))

I tried to follow the instructions here ([Getting started with Open NFC emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770774/getting-started-with-open-nfc-emulator)) but I can’t follow these two steps onwards as don’t have anywhere to enter an IP address within the emulated phone:

> --from the emulator, select Settings->Wireless & networks->NFC settings
>
> --enter 10.0.2.2 in IP Connection Center

**Results:** I'm not allowed to post images so I'll try to describe what I see when I run.
This is a filtered log extract although I’m not sure whether I’ve included what is important.

```
05-13 10:14:06.421        37-69/? W/SurfaceFlinger﹕ getting VSYNC period from fb HAL: 16666666
05-13 10:14:07.261        35-35/? I/OpenNFCServer﹕ Starting Open NFC server...        
05-13 10:14:07.261        35-35/? E/SIMULATOR﹕ 00001 ERROR HAL   : GetNALBinding
05-13 10:14:07.261        35-35/? I/OpenNFCServer﹕ serverStart : StartNFCC
05-13 10:14:07.641        35-35/? I/OPENNFC_SERVER﹕ 00001 LOG   NFCC_B: Open NFC v4.5.1 (Build 15725) is booting
05-13 10:14:07.641        35-35/? I/SIMULATOR﹕ 00002 LOG   HAL   : *****************  Reseting NFC Controller *********************
05-13 10:14:07.681        35-35/? I/OpenNFCServer﹕ serverStart : WaitForNFCCBoot
05-13 10:14:07.711       35-129/? I/OPENNFC_SERVER﹕ 00002 LOG   NAL   : ND->NFCC  NAL-ADMIN CMD-GET_PARAMETER HARDWARE_INFO
05-13 10:14:08.370        40-40/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ loadHwModule() Loaded primary audio interface from LEGACY Audio HW HAL (audio) handle 1
05-13 10:14:08.370        40-40/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ HAL output buffer size 1024 frames, normal mix buffer size 1024 frames
05-13 10:14:08.440        40-40/? I/AudioPolicyService﹕ Loaded audio policy from LEGACY Audio Policy HAL (audio_policy)
05-13 10:14:12.720       35-129/? I/SIMULATOR﹕ 00003 LOG   HAL   :        *****************  Reseting NFC Controller *********************
05-13 10:14:12.720       35-129/? I/OPENNFC_SERVER﹕ 00003 LOG   NAL   : ND->NFCC  NAL-ADMIN CMD-GET_PARAMETER HARDWARE_INFO
05-13 10:14:17.731       35-129/? I/SIMULATOR﹕ 00004 LOG   HAL   : *****************  Reseting NFC Controller *********************
05-13 10:14:17.731       35-129/? I/OPENNFC_SERVER﹕ 00004 LOG   NAL   : ND->NFCC  NAL-ADMIN CMD-GET_PARAMETER HARDWARE_INFO
05-13 10:14:22.730       35-129/? I/SIMULATOR﹕ 00005 LOG   HAL   : *****************  Reseting NFC Controller *********************
05-13 10:14:22.730       35-129/? I/OPENNFC_SERVER﹕ 00005 LOG   NAL   : ND->NFCC  NAL-ADMIN CMD-GET_PARAMETER HARDWARE_INFO
05-13 10:14:48.520      403-403/? I/NfcService﹕ Starting NFC service
05-13 10:14:48.700      403-403/? I/packages/apps/Nfc/nxp/jni/com_android_nfc.cpp﹕ NFC Service : loading JNI
05-13 10:14:49.710      403-403/? W/NfceeAccess﹕ could not find /etc/nfcee_access.xml, no NFCEE access allowed
05-13 10:14:49.710      403-403/? I/NfceeAccess﹕ read 0 signature(s) for NFCEE access
05-13 10:14:51.420      403-460/? D/NfcService﹕ NFC is on. Doing normal stuff
05-13 10:14:51.440      403-460/? I/NfcService﹕ Enabling NFC
05-13 10:14:51.640      403-460/? E/packages/apps/Nfc/nxp/jni/com_android_nfc_NativeNfcManager.cpp﹕ can't initialize NFC Manager
05-13 10:14:51.640      403-460/? W/NfcService﹕ Error enabling NFC
```

When I click on the NFC item within Wireless Setting I get the following log file entries:

```
05-13 10:42:27.887      403-885/? I/NfcService﹕ Enabling NFC
05-13 10:42:27.917      403-885/? E/packages/apps/Nfc/nxp/jni/com_android_nfc_NativeNfcManager.cpp﹕ can't initialize NFC Manager
05-13 10:42:27.917      403-885/? W/NfcService﹕ Error enabling NFC
```

**Connection Centre v4.5.2 (Build 16234)** : Log records :

```
Client source <machinename>;Unknown;nfcc_hal;NFC Controller (NFC HAL);NFC Controller (NFC HAL);10;connected to provider souce <machinename>;NfcSImulator;nfcc_hal;NFC Controller (NFC HAL);NFC Device #1;10;Application name NfcSimulator
```

The NFCC tab indicates there are no NFC Controller's available ("no device available" on the 1st two tabs)

**NFC Controller Simulator v4.5.2 (build 16324)** doesn't seem to have any lights lit up.

This question may be the same as this one ([Open NFC Simulator not working for Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523019/open-nfc-simulator-not-working-for-android-emulator?rq=1)) but it's hard to tell and the existing question is unanswered.