# how Install the Open NFC Add-on in my Android SDK environment

Tags: android, nfc

**I want to Install the Open NFC Add-on in my Android SDK environment.
 but I do not know how to do!**

In real, Using the new target provided in this Add-On, I can create a new Android Virtual Device (AVD) embedding Open NFC and running the Android Emulator on this AVD, I can use NFC features in the emulator. The emulator actually connects to the Connection Center tool.
I can use either the NFC Simulator or the MicroRead development kit driven by the Connection Center in this environment.

Comment: provide more details on OS version, environment details (windows / linux )

Comment: in real, i do not know how should i relate between android sdk in eclipse and nfc simulator? i run them on the windows 7.

Comment: did you read the pdf that comes within the download archive?

Comment: After adding the open_nfc to sdk - add-on, it isn't visible in sdk manager in Android studio

Answer (score 3):

1. You can download the zip file from
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-nfc/files/Open%20NFC%204.4.1%20%2813312%29/Open%20NFC%20SDK%20for%20Android%20v4.4.1%20%2813751%29.zip/download

and extract the "addon_open_nfc_4.4.1_android_4.0.3" named folder and paste it to the add-on folder of your android sdk installed location

1. Open SDK manager-> virtual devices->New->name your AVD and select Open-NFC as your target.

Comment: How to add the same in Android Studio? I don't have SDK Manager.

Comment: I don't have any add-on folder. Should I create one ?

Comment: Arun Raj.. After adding the **open_nfc** to *sdk* **-** *add-on*, it isn't visible in `sdk manager` in Android studio. I've tried *restarting, Invalidate caches, clean, rebuild* etc. but nothing works. what to do?

Comment: This post is too old. I did it for a Android ICS. Not sure it works now