# Open NFC emulator (NFC unavailable )

Tags: nfc, open-nfc

I have followed steps for setting Open NFC  Emulator .when  i try emulator setting

select `Settings->Wireless & networks->NFC settings`

The newly created AVD does not allow any changes. The check box for NFC settings is disabled  and below it I have `(Android Beam Unavailable because NFC is turned off)`

How can I apply NFC settings?
How does one turn on NFC in the emulator?

Comment: it is not possible to activate NFC on emulator.

Comment: i think open NFC Simulator for android is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your AVD with the OpenNFC Add-on it is possible to activate NFC.

But it is done not in the settings, but in the separate application "Settings OpenNFC".

For full algo for setting OpenNFC simulator refere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944968/222892).

Comment: NFC settings does not open that's the problem . [Emulator snapshot](http://s23.postimg.org/4aotdj9vv/android_NFC.png)

Comment: You give the snapshot of the wireless settings. In this emulator in applications there is a separate application "Settings OpenNFC" - enabling NFC is done there.

Comment: I don't have any "Settings OpenNFC" Application in emulator.Can you provide any snapshot of it? .

Comment: Thanks a lot.Using compiled android sdk  i am able to have "Setting OpenNFC " application

Comment: i also need that compile sdk can you please share it here