# Android application development using NFC with emulator

Tags: android, nfc

I am a newbie to android app development and trying to develop a NFC app. I don't have NFC enabled android phone with me. I have installed NFC controller simulator to emulate virtual cards but I am unable to enable the NFC option inside the wireless and settings in emulator. Attached is the snapshot link of my emulator.
[image]
Plz let me know how to enable the option.

Comment: I dont think you can test NFC in emulator, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you can surely test nfc over enulator.. check this link http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/android/

Comment: @Hardik4560 well i am newbie but i am very familiar with all the concepts. I just cant get around to enable the NFC option even after following all the steps mentioned at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770774/getting-started-with-open-nfc-emulator?rq=1