# Is it possible to test NFC feature in Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, nfc

I am trying to test NFC demo application. but I don't have NFC-enabled devices. So I want to try it on an emulator. I have done some google but I have not got any solution.

I tried following  [Open NFC Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770774/getting-started-with-open-nfc-emulator)  but this question is very old. the link provided in this question about open android emulator is not accessible.

Comment: no it is not possible